# JsonDeserialization on @RequestBody in Spring boot - Res

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Could someone please help me understand what could the one thing that could cause `JsonDeserializer` not to be invoked on  `@RequestBody`?

```
@RequestMappy(method=POST, value = /InfraSpec)
ResponseEntity<InfraSpec> createInfrastructure(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, @RequestBody InfraSpec infraSpec)
{
    InfraSpec infs = infrRepository.saveAnFlush(infraSpec);
    ResponseEntity<InfraSpec> resEntity = new ResponeEntity(infs, HttpStatus.Ok);
    return resEntity ;
}



@Entity
@JsonDeserialiser(using= InfraSpecDeserializer)
public Class InfraSpec
{
    //....
}


public class InfraSpecDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<InfraSpec> {
    @Override
    public InfraSpec deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        InfraSpec ifs = new InfraSpec();
        // logic to parse the jsoneNode and populate ifs
        return ifs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not only is this post poorly formatted, but the code you posted is obviously broken. If you do not want to post production code, that is fine. But please post something that will at least compile

Comment: My apologies and thank you for your time. I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for poorly formatted post and incomplete post.

The good news is that I figured out the issue: the issue was with me using org.codehouse.jackson....

when I changed my code  to use com.fasterxml.jackson.***  The JsonDeserializer was invoked as expected.